# How to say "Smooth!" in Esperanto

Tags: translation

I want to say "smooth" in Esperanto.
Or something like "es läuft wie geschmiert", "det går som på räls". Is there an Esperanto expression for this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean “smooth” as in stylish or as in without problem? Sorry for the stupid question but I don’t understand the other two languages.

Comment: Without problems. Haha. Sorry. 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two possibilities with source:

- *Ĉio iras glate.* (*iri glate* taken from [here](http://www.robkeetlaer.nl/esperanto/proverbaro/proverbo_001235.htm))
- *Ĉio fluas glate.* (*flui glate* taken from [here](http://www.robkeetlaer.nl/esperanto/proverbaro/proverbo_002598.htm))

Comment: Do those sentences mean _no problems_?

Comment: Yes, they are established metaphorical ways of saying that everything works without problems. i have the impression that the first one is more common than the second.

Answer (score 4):

In the *Frazeologio* by Sabine Fiedler, there is the phrase *glite kaj glate* IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

Ĉi tiu ekzemplo estas el *Patroj kaj filoj* (tradukita de Kabe):

- *Bazarov murmuris, sed dank’ al la ordo en la domo de sinjorino Odincov, en kiu ĉio “ruliĝis kvazaŭ sur la reloj”, la vivo de Bazarov kaj de Arkadio estis tiel facila kaj agrabla de ŝi.*

(La citiloj devenas de la originalo.)

Answer (score 3):

"Senprobleme" suits perfectly, in my opinion.